# My AJAX function is returning null

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm working with CakePHP and I would like to fetch some content in my database with AJAX. I've been working on PHP code and it seems to work... However, the ajax call is not working... It returns me a "null" instead of the json content.

Here is my code :

```
<a onclick="updateResult()">TEST</a>

<div id="test"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateResult(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/regions/articles/viewresult',
            data : {
                category_id : "35"
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(html, textStatus) {
                alert('Success ' + textStatus + html);
            },
            error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error ! ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

By the way, /regions/articles/viewresult is returning

```
[{"id":1,"title":"regionacal","body":"regionacaltest","category_id":35,"created":"2016-04-02T22:44:21+0000","modified":"2016-04-02T22:44:21+0000"}]
```

But the success function in my JS returns me "null"...

Do you know why?

Comment: By "return", do you mean "show in an alert"? Because there is no useful place (wrt. the output) for a `return` in that code.

Comment: Yes "the return" in the alert. It show "Success success null".

Comment: How is it confirmed that the response shown is what the server is returning?

Comment: This is wat I suppose... When I browse  /regions/articles/viewresult I see the correct result.

Comment: Are you sure that  `category_id : "35"` (sent data) should be `string` instead of `int`?

Comment: @SausauRJ But what shows up in the *Network Requests* of the Browser Tools? A normal web request/response is not the same as the *actual* request/response.

Comment: @itsgoingdown That particular distinction is actually lost in the form data encoding (the `data` option is not JSON-ified) - although the issue could still be related to other 'non-expected' input.

Comment: The send data doesn't matter at the moment, in fact, I've forced a value in my PHP code.

Comment: In Network Requests, I can see that the ajax request is sent. When I try to preview the response, it's a "null" (status code 200, header json)

Answer (score 0):

Make your request towards: `/regions/articles/viewresult.json`

And make sure you return the json properly from the controller method.

To serialize the **response** view variable.

```
$this->set('_serialize', ['response']);
```

To serialize **all** available view variables

```
$this->set('_serialize', true);
```

Also make sure your routes.php has the json extension enabled.

```
$routes->extensions(['json']);
```